# canvas arc function broken in Chrome 27.0?

Tags: google-chrome, canvas

I have a bizarre problem with canvas and Chrome 27.0:

After large amounts of drawing on a canvas, using the arc function draws solid squares in Chrome on OS X, but works fine in Safari, Firefox on the same OS X machine, and in IE10, Chrome and Firefox on Windows it's fine all the time.

The problem is not reproducible without running the giant wad of code beforehand, so I'm assuming it has something to do with what's being done beforehand, but here is some information, perhaps someone can point me in a direction I haven't thought of yet.

This is the code that fails:

```
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)";
    ctx.arc(cx*sfx, cy*sfy, width*sfy, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
```

I can get it to draw the circle in Chrome by not doing the arc over 2pi, but 1.9999pi. This code works:

```
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)";
    ctx.arc(cx*sfx, cy*sfy, width*sfy, 0, Math.PI * 1.999, false);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
```

What also works, is to remove the beginPath() statement. Then however, a line is drawn from where the last object was drawn on the canvas to the beginning point of the circle.

I've tried reordering, removing doubling the begin/end path statements, all to no effect apart from the described.

Any clues anyone?

Cheers

- Balt

Comment: Same issue here. (Windows 7 Chrome 27.0.1453.110)

Comment: I have (for now) changed all arc code drawing circles to use Math.PI * 1.9999 instead of Math.PI*2. Obviously that's not a good solution, but it bridges things for now.

Comment: Ah yeah. The problem went away for me , still see it on an old version of my canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, I've used the same hack at first, but later I added a moveTo

```
  ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);

  /*
  Chrome suddenly started drawing a filled square (2013 May 26)
  can't get the filled square though in jsfiddle

  first try was changing it to
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*1.999, false)
  which worked, but then added the moveTo, which also made it work again
  */
```